# My app is very big in size (10GB) . How can I see data or wrong code?

Tags: java, android, database, apk, realm-mobile-platform

[image]

Hello everybody, I have a problem can you help me ? My android app's apk size 76 mb . But App data size be +10gb and every time be large when running app. How can I see data/data folder without rooting ? Why app data size is so large ?

Tablet = Samsung Tab S2

Comment: Thank you for answer .I fixed my problem . I used to Realmdb in my project. RealmDb was happening very large size when running app . I resolved with compactOnLaunch method when realm init.

Comment: I saw external(data/data folder)  with "adb backup" command

Answer (score 1):

That is not the storage being used by your app. That is the overall device storage, just as:

- The mobile data usage shown there is for the device
- The battery usage shown there is for the device
- The memory usage shown there is for the device

The manufacturer of your device elected to show device values on a screen that is otherwise dedicated to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps taking photos or recording videos in your app? Any media that is created in your app and stored in the app's local storage is added to the app's size on the device.

I had a similar problem where we were creating temp image files but never clearing them so the app would become bigger and bigger over time. To fix this we simply deleted the temp files after we were done with them (e.g. after they have been uploaded)

The app's DB can also contribute to the overall size but unless you are creating a huge amount of entries I don't think this would be the cause